# Does it make sense to learn .NET Core 3.0 Now?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Currently I am learning asp.net core , and I found a book about .net core 3.0 , Is this still true or there are too many differences between .net core 3.0 and .net core 5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to Asp.net core than 3.0 is good enough to start. Most basic this are the same between the two versions. And then you can pickup the newer changes faster.

Answer (score 1):

Yah, for sure.

.NET 5 was introduced after .NET Core 3 (Cross Plataform) and .NET Framework 4.8 (Windows Only), that's where the 5 comes from [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five).

What's the big changes of .NET Core 3 to this next version .NET 5?

1. More choice on runtime experiences;
2. Java interoperability available on all platform;
3. Objective-C and Swift interoperability supported on multiple operating systems;

You can  read more about it [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/);

As said by Richard, on the article above:

> Everything you love about .NET Core will continue to exist.

So, dont worry about wasting time on that, go for it.

Enjoy the journey.